# Using 2 BERTs to create a multimodal model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to create a multimodal BERT model for text classification. The first model will be a classical BERT and the second model an emotion recognition BERT outputting 4 values for joyness, anger etc. The second model is from [here](https://%20https://huggingface.co/cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-emotion).
I would like for these 2 models run in parallel and lastly their outputs to be concatenated in a single dense layer.
However, the Emotion BERT model is pre-trained and needs no further training.
What i have done so far:
**Imports and initializations:**

```
!pip install -q -U "tensorflow-text==2.8.*"
!pip install -q tf-models-official==2.7.0

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
# Some other key imports
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import shutil
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax
import csv
import urllib.request
    
import tensorflow_text as text
from official.nlp import optimization  # to create AdamW optimizer

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')


def preprocess(text):
new_text = []
for t in text.split(" "):
    t = '@user' if t.startswith('@') and len(t) > 1 else t
    t = 'http' if t.startswith('http') else t
    new_text.append(t)
return " ".join(new_text)
#@title Choose a BERT model to fine-tune

bert_model_name = 'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8'  #@param ["bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12", "bert_en_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12", "bert_multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-128_A-2", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-256_A-4", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-512_A-8", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-768_A-12", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-128_A-2", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-256_A-4", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-768_A-12", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-128_A-2", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-256_A-4", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-512_A-8", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-768_A-12", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-128_A-2", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-256_A-4", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-512_A-8", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-768_A-12", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-128_A-2", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-256_A-4", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-512_A-8", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-768_A-12", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-128_A-2", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-256_A-4", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-512_A-8", "small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12", "albert_en_base", "electra_small", "electra_base", "experts_pubmed", "experts_wiki_books", "talking-heads_base"]

map_name_to_handle = {
    'bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3',
    'bert_en_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3',
    'bert_multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-128_A-2/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-256_A-4/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-512_A-8/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-768_A-12/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-128_A-2/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-256_A-4/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-768_A-12/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-128_A-2/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-256_A-4/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-512_A-8/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-768_A-12/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-128_A-2/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-256_A-4/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-512_A-8/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-768_A-12/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-128_A-2/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-256_A-4/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-512_A-8/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-768_A-12/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-128_A-2/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-256_A-4/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-512_A-8/1',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1',
    'albert_en_base':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/albert_en_base/2',
    'electra_small':
        'https://tfhub.dev/google/electra_small/2',
    'electra_base':
        'https://tfhub.dev/google/electra_base/2',
    'experts_pubmed':
        'https://tfhub.dev/google/experts/bert/pubmed/2',
    'experts_wiki_books':
        'https://tfhub.dev/google/experts/bert/wiki_books/2',
    'talking-heads_base':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/talkheads_ggelu_bert_en_base/1',
}

map_model_to_preprocess = {
    'bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'bert_en_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_cased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-6_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-10_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-128_A-2':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-256_A-4':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'bert_multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_multi_cased_preprocess/3',
    'albert_en_base':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/albert_en_preprocess/3',
    'electra_small':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'electra_base':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'experts_pubmed':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'experts_wiki_books':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
    'talking-heads_base':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3',
}

tfhub_handle_encoder = map_name_to_handle[bert_model_name]
tfhub_handle_preprocess = map_model_to_preprocess[bert_model_name]

print(f'BERT model selected           : {tfhub_handle_encoder}')
print(f'Preprocess model auto-selected: {tfhub_handle_preprocess}')


bert_preprocess_model = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess)
bert_model = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder)
```

**Model Code:**

```
 task='emotion'
MODEL = f"cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-{task}"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)

# PT
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)

def build_classifier_model():
      # BERT
      text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
      preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess, name='preprocessing')
      encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
      encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
      outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
      net = outputs['pooled_output']
      net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)

      # Emotion BERT
      encoded_input = tokenizer(str(text_input), return_tensors='pt')
      output = model(**encoded_input)
    

      # concatenation
      concatted = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([net, output])
      net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None, name='classifier')(net)
      return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)




   Trying an exmaple like below :

    text_test =['this is such an amazing movie!']
    classifier_model = build_classifier_model()
```

produces this error:

```
    ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(None, 512), SequenceClassifierOutput(loss=None, logits=(1, 4), hidden_states=None, attentions=None)]
```

The ouput printed is :

```
    SequenceClassifierOutput(loss=None, logits=tensor([[-0.0363,  0.7950,  0.0233,  0.1205]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>), hidden_states=None, attentions=None)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious, why use `return_tensors='pt'` instead of `return_tensors='tf'`?

Comment: @AloneTogether No reason, just copied code from documentation. Using 'tf produces an error though.

Comment: What does `output` look like when you print it?

Comment: @AloneTogether I editted the question, i also tried to reshape via a reshape layer but it does not work.

Comment: @AloneTogether Yes, i editted the question again so that it has the mandatory code to run.

Comment: You forgot the tokenizer and model inside `build_classifier_model`? Where are they defined?

Comment: @AloneTogether Sorry, you are right. I updated.